# Laravel "Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\Dispatcher] is not instantiable."

Tags: php, laravel

As the title itself says, I've got the following issue: 
`Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\Dispatcher] is not instantiable.`.
I'm trying to use a custom script and include the default Laravel classes

```
require_once dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once dirname(__DIR__) . '/bootstrap/app.php';

use App\Mail\ChangeInStatusMail;
use App\Jobs\SendEmail;
```

After using SendEmail::dispatch() I get the previously mentioned error.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Since I have experience of updating from laravel 5.2 to 5.8 or so, I had to replace '`Collective\Bus\BusServiceProvider`', with '`Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider`', in providers array in config/app.php.

This worked for me and the error no more appeared on Password reset link click

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel v.`5.2` the command bus has been removed. Because of this you need to install it mazually from [here](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/bus) to make it work.

Comment: I'm using Laravel 5.8.7 and PHP 7.4.0 and I get the following error when I try to get the package with the composer:
"requires ext-json ^1.5 -> the requested PHP extension json has the wrong version (7.4.0) installed."